# Tuning nHibernate Query

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I need some help to tune a Nhibernate Query.

I have two entities

```
public class Parent
{    
   public int Id {get; set; }    
   public List<Child> Childs {get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
   public int ChildId {get; set;}
   public Parent Parent {get; set;}
}
```

I need return a List which is a select of all child lists of all parents.
So, I did it like this.

```
public IList<Child> GetChilds(IEnumerable<Parent> parents)
{
    var data = this.Sessao.QueryOver<Parent>()
                          .Where(Restrictions.In("Parent.Id", parents.Select(x => x.Id).ToList()))
                          .List();

    var childs = new List<Child>();

    foreach (var parent in data)
    {
        childs.AddRange(parent.childs);
    }

    return childs;
}
```

It works, but it's generating a select to get parents plus n selects to get childs and I think it's possible get all childs with only one query.

Comment: Is parent a nulllable relationship?  In other words is it required that a child have a parent?

Comment: Yes, it's required that a child have a parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with the linq provider like this:

```
public IList<Child> GetChilds(IEnumerable<Parent> parents)
{
    return this.Sessao.Query<Child>()
                      .Where(x => parents.Select(x => x.Id).ToList().Contains(x.Parent.Id))
                      .List();
}
```

or something like this with the QueryOver provider:

```
public IList<Child> GetChilds(IEnumerable<Parent> parents)
{
    Parent parentAlias = null;
    this.Sessao.QueryOver<Wave>()
            .Inner.JoinAlias(x => x.Parent, () => parentAlias)
            .WhereRestrictionOn(() => parentAlias.Id).IsIn(parents.Select(x => x.Id).ToList())
}
```

The above examples are pseudocode so they may not be exact but should be very close.